# polymer build on a Polymer Element containing multiple child elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm a bit confused as to how to build a Polymer Element 1.x, scaffolded by running `$ polymer init`

What I did so far:

- Run `$ polymer init`
- Coded my element in ES6 without changing *any* of the directory structure/paths.
- Run `$ polymer build`

#### Current project structure

It's identical to the structure created by running `$ polymer init` with no changes whatsoever in the directories/path references.

```
/bower_components
/demo/index.html

/test/my-element_test.html
/test/child-element_test.html

my-element.html
child-element.html
bower.json
polymer.json
index.html
README.md
```

#### Goal is to create ES5 versions of the elements.

I'd like to create built versions of my element, transpiled from ES6 to ES5.

Ideally my project structure would look like this:

```
/bower_components
/demo/index.html

/build/bower_components
/build/my-element-es5.html
/build/child-element-es5.html

/test/my-element_test.html
/test/child-element_test.html

my-element.html
child-element.html
bower.json
polymer.json
index.html
README.md
```

Running `$ polymer build` only creates a `build/default/index.html`, which only contains an `<iron-component-page>` referencing my element.

---

Does `$ polymer build` work on single elements created with `$ polymer init` or is it just for app-style projects?

If it does work for pure elements, what am I missing here?

**Note:** My element 'project' contains 2 elements, `my-element.html` and `child-element.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems `$ polymer build` is not supporting Polymer Element projects at all.

See [this Issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/453) for more info and watch [this  S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722220/transpiling-a-polymer-element) on how to do single element transpilation