# Transpiling a Polymer Element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm scaffolding Polymer 1.x Elements using `$ polymer init`. These elements are **not Polymer applications**. They are just elements.

All my elements are coded in ES6. I'd like to transpile my elements down to ES5.

Considering that `$ polymer build` [does not support single Element projects](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/453#issuecomment-263734091), what solutions can I use to achieve the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpiling Polymer to es5 is done in 3 steps:

1. [Vulcanize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vulcanize) your element(s) by inlining the script and CSS:

   `vulcanize element.html --inline-script --inline-css > element.v.html`
2. Pipe the output to [Cripser](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper). Crisper is a tool that extracts all inline  and creates a standalone .js file.

   `crisper -s element.v.html -h element.v.html -j element.js`
3. Run the standalone JS file through Babel:

   `babel element.js -o element.js`

Old Answer(wrong):You need to use [vulcanize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vulcanize) directly. for instance:

```
 vulcanize target.html > build.html
```

Comment: Vulcanize doesn't deal with transpilation, it's just a bundler

Comment: Shit you are right see the edit this does work definitly